# Process onclick function after ajax call <f:ajax>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to select and focus to choosed component ID after submit a form (ajax call).

```
<script>
var myFunc = function() {
  document.getElementById('form:#{bean.componentId}').focus();
  document.getElementById('form:#{bean.componentId}').select();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  myFunc();
});
</script>

<h:form id="form">
  <h:commandButton action="#{bean.save}" onclick="return myFunc();" ...>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
  </h:commandButton>
  ...
</h:form>
```

This solution is working, but problem is, that `<f:ajax>` is called AFTER `onclick`, so the the form is rendered after component selection, and focus is cleared.

How can I call my function AFTER the form is rendered?

**update:** (I've tried for example)

- add `onevent="myFunc();"` to `f:ajax` => leads to refreshing page
- add `onevent="myFunc()"` to `f:ajax` => same behaviour as `onclick` attribute
- next `f:ajax` with `onevent` attr. => still the same

**update2** (how it should works):

- submit button is ajax called
- form is cleaned as needed
- appropriate field is focused (depended on some user choosed factors)

Comment: There is an "oncomplete"-attribut in primefaces commandbutton and in richfaces commandbutton.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `onevent` handler will actually be invoked three times and it should point to a function name, not the function itself. One time before the ajax request is been sent, one time after the ajax response is been arrived and one time when the HTML DOM is successfully updated. You should be checking the `status` property of the given data argument for that.

```
function listener(data) {
    var status = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" or "success".

    switch (status) {
        case "begin": // Before the ajax request is sent.
            // ...
            break;

        case "complete": // After the ajax response is arrived.
            // ...
            break;

        case "success": // After update of HTML DOM based on ajax response..
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

In your particular case, you thus just need to add a check if the status is `success`.

```
function myFunc(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        var element = document.getElementById('form:#{bean.componentId}');
        element.focus();
        element.select();
    }
}
```

And you need to reference the function by its name:

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="myFunc" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's strange, componentId is still the same now, it select always the same component..

Comment: That's a different problem. EL runs along with JSF at webserver, not along with HTML/JS in webbrowser. Look at the generated HTML output. You'll see that there's no `#{}` anymore in the JS function.

Comment: Aha (don't understand):-) ComponentId remains such as inicialized in bean.. Is that proble has some solution? I'm spinning in circle :(

Comment: JSF/EL produces HTML/JS code. They don't run in sync. The concrete functional requirement is not clear, so it's hard to propose a solution. It at least needs to be solved entirely in the client side.