# how to get the updated value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf

i have a jquery file that have :

```
document.getElementById('formId:someId').click();
bla = document.getElementById('formId:inputId3').value;            
              if(bla =="koko") {
 alert(" Done ");
 }
```

in jsf i have the method that change the value of the h:inputText :

```
 <h:inputText id="inputId3" value="#{gestionduplanning.testvalue2}" />

 <h:commandButton id="someId" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2()}" style="display:none">
 <f:ajax render="inputId3" execute="@all"/>  
 </h:commandButton>
```

and in the managed bean i have :

```
   public void exec2() {
    this.testvalue2 = "koko";    
   }
```

the problem i cant enter the `if` in Jquery because they still have the first default value before the change.

how i can update the update the inputText in the Jquery too be fore the Click on the button ??

Comment: The bits you're calling jQuery are just pure JavaScript. You don't appear to be using jQuery at all, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: i update the title too

Comment: @marouanoviche,  this might help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16444123/617373

Comment: do you think i have problem in logique that Javascript cant get the new value when he is already lunched ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this (its the general idea):

```
document.getElementById('formId:someId').click();
```

and add the following js function:

```
function doTheJs(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') {
        bla = document.getElementById('formId:inputId3').value;            
        if(bla =="koko") {
            alert(" Done ");
        }
    }
}
```

and your JSF:

```
<h:commandButton id="someId" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2()}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="inputId3" execute="@all" onevent="doTheJs"/>  
</h:commandButton>
```