# inputText inside table header: how to render only dataTable content

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I have a dataTable with a list of employees.
One column of the dataTable is the names of the employees.
I want to have an inputText inside the header of the column which the user can use to filter the employees by their names, e.g. when the user writes "smi" in the inputText, the dataTable should only show the employees with the name starting with "smi" like Smith. The table data should update while the user is writing into the inputText, that is why I am using ajax here.

This is my column:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Name
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="suchString" class="suchString"
            value="#{mitarbeiteransicht.suchString}">
                <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="suchString" render="ma-tabelle" />
            </h:inputText>
        </h:form>
    </f:facet>
            #{ma.bezeichnung}
</h:column>
```

ma-tabelle is my dataTable.

Everytime the table is rendered, the inputText inside the header is losing the focus and the user needs to click it again.

Is there a way around this? Is it possible to exclude the table headers when rerendering?

Comment: I would suggest to use `primefaces`.

Comment: Is there a way without using primefaces?

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540298/proccess-onclick-function-after-ajax-call-fajax

Comment: If you have an `<h:form/>` inside your datatable, does that mean you also have a form enclosing the datatable? Are you aware that nested forms are not allowed in HTML and will result in all manner of bugs?